# Target Unreachable, identifier 'Test' resolved to null

Tags: jsf, managed-bean, propertynotfoundexception

index.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
<head>
   <title>Title</title>

   <!-- CSS -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />

   <h:outputStylesheet>
   </h:outputStylesheet>
</head>
<body>
   <h:form>

      <h:button value="Yeni Kayıt Oluştur">
         <f:param name="kayitOlustur" value="20" />
      </h:button>

      <h:button value="Mevcut Kayıtları Listele">
         <f:param name="kayitListele" value="20" />
      </h:button>

      <h:button value="Mevcut Kayıtları Düzenle">
         <f:param name="kayitDuzenle" value="20" />
      </h:button>

   </h:form>

   <div style="min-height:20px;"></div>

   <!-- FORM -->
   <h:form>
      <h:panelGrid columns="2">
         <h:outputText value="Ad &amp; Soyad Giriniz:"></h:outputText>
         <h:inputText value="#{Test.adSoyad}"></h:inputText>

         <h:outputText value="Cinsiyet Seçiniz:"></h:outputText>
         <h:selectManyCheckbox value="#{Test.cinsiyet}">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Kadın" itemValue="Kadın"></f:selectItem>
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Erkek" itemValue="Erkek"></f:selectItem>
         </h:selectManyCheckbox>

         <h:outputText value="Adresinizi Giriniz:"></h:outputText>
         <h:inputTextarea value="#{Test.adres}"></h:inputTextarea>

         <h:outputText value="İl Seçimi Yapınız:"></h:outputText>
         <h:selectOneMenu value="#OzgurSoftwareClass.il">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="İstanbul" itemValue="İstanbul"></f:selectItem>
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="İzmir" itemValue="İzmir"></f:selectItem>
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Ankara" itemValue="Ankara"></f:selectItem>
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Diğer" itemValue="Diğer"></f:selectItem>
         </h:selectOneMenu>

         <h:outputText value="Parola Belirleyiniz:"></h:outputText>
         <h:inputSecret value="{#Test.parola}"></h:inputSecret>

         <h:outputText value="Kayıt Şartları Kabul Ediyorum"></h:outputText>
         <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{Test.sartlar}" />

         <h:outputText value="Kayıt Oluştur"></h:outputText>
         <h:commandButton value="Gönder" update="display" />

      </h:panelGrid>

      <h:panelGrid columns="1">
         <h4>Kayıt Edilen Üyenin Bigileri</h4>
         <!--<h:outputText value="{#Test.bilgi}" />
         <h:outputText value="{#Test.adSoyad}" />
         <h:outputText value="{#Test.cinsiyet}" />
         <h:outputText value="{#Test.il}" />
         <h:outputText value="{#Test.parola}" />-->

         <h:outputText id="bilgi" value="#{Test.bilgi}" />
         <h:outputText id="adSoyad" value="#{Test.adSoyad}" />
         <h:outputText id="cinsiyet" value="#{Test.cinsiyet}" />
         <h:outputText id="il" value="#{Test.il}" />
         <h:outputText id="parola" value="#{Test.parola}" />
      </h:panelGrid>
   </h:form>

</body>
</html>
```

Test.java

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@ManagedBean(name = "Test")
@RequestScoped

public class Test{

private String adSoyad;
private List<String> cinsiyet=new ArrayList<String>();
private String adres;
private String il;
private String parola;
private boolean sartlar;
private String bilgi;

public String getAdSoyad(){
    return adSoyad;
}

public void setAdSoyad(String adSoyad){
    this.adSoyad = adSoyad;
}

public List<String> getCinsiyet(){
    return cinsiyet;
}

public void setCinsiyet(List<String> cinsiyet){
    this.cinsiyet = cinsiyet;
}

public String getAdres(){
    return adres;
}

public void setAdres(String adres){
    this.adres = adres;
}

public String getIl(){
    return il;
}

public void setIl(String il){
    this.il = il;
}

public String getSartlar(){
    if (!sartlar)
    {
        bilgi="Şartları Kabul Ediniz!";
    }
    else
    {
        bilgi="Şartları Kabul Ettiniz!";
    }
    return bilgi;
}
}
```

error:

> javax.servlet.ServletException: /index.xhtml @41,61
>   value="#{Test.adSoyad}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'Test'
>   resolved to null
>
> javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /index.xhtml @41,61
>   value="#{Test.adSoyad}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'Test'
>   resolved to null
>
> javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Target Unreachable, identifier
>   'Test' resolved to null

Comment: Are yor tried to use @ManagedBean without `name` in your xhtml file as `#{test.adSoyad}` ? What is the result, the same?

Comment: Yes, I was try but still doesnt work.

Comment: Did you post the error in google? There are over  a dozen Q/A in Stackoverflow (and most are visible in the related area on the right here) (and I corrected your tagging)

Comment: I already check other Q/A but they are not helpfull to me.